# How to change display mode based on result count (using grouping field)?

Tags: views

I need to create a view similar to below -

Term 01  // has more than one node associated

- Teaser A
- Teaser B

Term 02 // has only one node associated

- Full node C

Term 03 // more than one associated node

- Teaser D
- Teaser E

I guess 'View (Display) mode' should be the one to rescue and I have also found a solution that uses 'hook_views_pre_render' to change the view mode dynamically (see - http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-views-pre-render-alter-display), when not using grouping by field.

However, the above solution does not work when grouping these teasers by field, since the $result->count is already set to the total number of results returned. Any ideas to solve this would be appreciated.

-gnat